# Override function parameters /

Tags: c++, templates, overriding

Let's say we have a Collection class like:

```
class CCollection {

public:
    void add(B& b);
    void remove(B& b);
    void doSomethingWithAllObjects();

protected:
    std::vector<B*> bs;

}
```

Where B is an abstract class and the specific behaviour of

```
doSomethingWithAllObjects();
```

depends on the concrete type of B, call it C.

Is there a way to derive CCollection and let the methods

```
add(B b);
remove(B b);
```

just accept the derived type?

I thought of something like overriding the methods like this:

```
class D : A{
public:
    void add(C c);
    void remove(C c);
    void doSomethingWithAllObjects();
private:
    std::vector<B*> bs;      
}
```

or a generic javaish construct like

```
template<class T : B>
class C {
    ...//do lots of stuff
}
```

The derivations are almost 100% the same. But you must not mix different derivations of B.

I already read its nearly impossible to restrict template classes to certain types but there has to be a way to avoid writing a whole class for every derivation of B. The point is, I need the functions defined in B, so I can't use a simple template

```
template<class T>
class B{
  ....
}
```

Of course I could assume other programmers just hand over the right type to the right CCollection but this can't be the spirit. What I want is to force other programmers to add just one type of Bs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There seems to be a fundamental design problem if I'm reading your question correctly.  `virtual` functions allow behavior to be determined at *runtime*.  And changing the type of that parameter would be something that's enforced at compile time - before runtime conditions are known.  What do you hope to enforce at compile time?

Comment: Just accept the derived type? isn't the base class abstract? you can not declare an object of it. So how can you pass it to add and remove? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not sure how you are converting from value parameter `add(B b)` into a pointer to store in your vector `std::vector<B*>` seems the only address you can take is that of a parameter which dies at the end of the function `add()`

Comment: Thank you for the quick repsonses. I changed the method parameters to references. I need to make sure that you can pass just one derived type of b and not all kind of bs. The same what <T extends B> would do in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but I think you are loooking for a simple ***template non-member type function***. The template function can be used to make sure that types match.

```
template<typename T>
void global_adder(const T& cl, const T& toadd) {
    cl.add(toadd);
}
```

- Since doesn't do type deductions based on inheritances,  this will
  make sure that A is not added to B or B to C and so on. To be added
  both args must have the same type. Nothing more.
- You keep your class method in the base class only. Make it
  `protected` and add this function as `friend`.
- That way you will now that no one can call `a.add` or `b.add` from
  somewhere else (*will not be able to add different type to a certain
  class*).
- The only way to add or remove an element will be through the template
  functions which make sure that types match.

Answer (score -1):

You can make an abstract base collection class like

```
class BaseCollection {
  public:
    void doSomethingWithAllObjects();
  protected:
    void addInternal(B* b); // consumes the element

    std::vector<B*> bs;  // or better use vector<shared_ptr> for reference count
};

template <typename C>
class Collection : public BaseCollection {
  public:
    void add(const C& c) {
      C* my_copy = new C(c);  // suppose we have a copy constructor
      addInternal(my_copy);
    }
};
```

If you try to instantiate `Collection<C>` where `C` is not a subclass of `B`, you will get a compile error.

Comment: Don't pass pointers into the Collection. Either pass a reference thus indicating that you are not taking ownership (which you then convert to pointer for storage in bs). OR pass a smart pointer which indicates you are taking ownership (as defined by the type of smart pointer).

Comment: vector<shared_ptr> is not better. You are mixing ownership symantics. Define the ownership symantics that will allow you to define the storage criteria.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, because I have tons of duplicated code for every new derivation. I have just posted an example. My real collection class is a bit more complex ;-)